# Bind to MainWindow DataContext property from child control viewmodels property in main window data context viewmodel markup

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel, datacontext

1. I have a UserControl (UC1) which has a data context : ViewModelOne.
2. I have a MainWindow app that uses the UC1 as a child control.
3. This MainWindow has a data context too : ViewModelTwo.

Need to bind a property in the view model's data context markup declaration, like this:`

```
<Window x:Class="control.controlnamespace" 
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace"..>
<Window.DataContext>
*<vm:ViewModelTwo Property="{Binding SomeProperty, ElementName=myControl}"/>* <-- Issue Here
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
   <UC1 x:Name="myControl"/>
</Grid>
```

That's where I am having the trouble no update is happening and the binding isn't happening either.

Comment: I am still not clear about your problem. Can you explain it with an example?

Comment: It seems that the property I set at the data context level <Window.DataContext>
 Property="{Binding SomeProperty, ElementName=myControl}"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this:

Setting up or trying to setup a property in the viewmodel's declaration inside the window datacontext markup is wrong and won't have any effect. This because by the time this context is set it's under a different thread therefore no updates or changes are being notified.

WRONG --->

```
<Window.DataContext>
<vm:ViewModelTwo Property="{Binding SomeProperty, ElementName=myControl}"/>* <-- Issue Here
</Window.DataContext>
```

So the way to resolve this is to actually get the current loaded element (this could be user control, window etc)
CORRECT -->

```
<Window Name="myWindowName">
    <Window.DataContext>
         <vm:ViewModel />
     </Window.DataContext>

     <control:Control x:Name="myControl" PropertyToBind="{Binding Path=DataContext.Property, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=myWindowName or myUserControlName}" >
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this:

In your MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window ........ >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ViewModelOne />
    </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

In your ViewModelOne:

```
public class ViewModelOne : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    .....
    .....

    private string _UCText;
    public string UCText
    {
        get
        {
            return _UCText;
        }
        set
        {
            _UCText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UCText");
        }
    }

    // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
    .....
    .....
}
```

In your UserControl:

```
<UserControl ...... >
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:ViewModelTwo />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.UCText, 
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor 
                                                             AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />

</UserControl>
```

If you have any problems with the above code then feel free to ask.

Comment: What if instead of binding to a Textbox you bind this to a property Inside ViewModelTwo like this: vm:ViewModelTwo Property={Binding Path=UCText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor...

Comment: I don't understand you clearly. But what I understand is you want to get UCText's value (declared in ViewModelOne) in a property inside your ViewModelTwo.. Right?????

Comment: Yeah! that's what I'm trying to accomplish. not sure if I can do that or not.

Comment: The property you want to bind inside ViewModelTwo must be a dependency property, because only dependency property can have binding.

Comment: Then I think my provided solution should work. And if it does not work then please post a sample project.